# File name using find

Tags: bash, search, find

How to get the file name while using find command? When I use find command to search particular type of files from a directory and subdirectories, I get the whole path of that file, how do I get the file name only? The problem I am facing is when I am moving that found file to archive directory, it says "there is no such directory" and it is because of whole path I am getting while searching for the file.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your logic.  Can you give a use case where this is used, before you select an answer?

Comment: well I am looking for a way through go through a directory and find a file with particular name , copy that file to remove server and then move that file to archive directory with time stamp. I am using 'find' for looping over files in that particular directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `basename` command will give you just the name of the file and not the full path, which you can execute on your found file like this:

```
find . -name filename -exec basename {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `find ... -printf '%f\n'`

Or, to solve your stated problem:

`find ... -name FOO -print0 | xargs --no-run-if-empty --null mv --target-directory=TARGET`